# Tensorflow-gpu 1.9 is not working on Pycharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, cudnn

I can't import tensorflow in pycharm, it raises the following error:

```
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 9.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

I checked this cudart file and its added in %PATH%

It is working on CLI and python shell perfectly.

I have

```
CUDA v9.0
cuDNN v7.0.5
tensorflow-gpu v1.9
```

echo %PATH%

```
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;
```

Directory of cudar64_90.dll:

```
07/27/2018  02:53 PM    <DIR>          .
07/27/2018  02:53 PM    <DIR>          ..
09/02/2017  03:45 PM           163,840 bin2c.exe
07/27/2018  02:28 PM    <DIR>          crt
05/16/2018  11:18 PM        55,161,856 cublas64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:45 PM           347,136 cuda-memcheck.exe
09/02/2017  03:45 PM         3,930,112 cudafe++.exe
09/02/2017  03:45 PM         4,226,048 cudafe.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM           299,520 cudart32_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM           373,760 cudart64_90.dll
11/16/2017  07:51 PM       286,877,184 cudnn64_7.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM       131,197,952 cufft64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM           199,680 cufftw64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         3,575,808 cuinj32_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         4,495,360 cuinj64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:45 PM         1,411,072 cuobjdump.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        48,057,344 curand64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        75,222,016 cusolver64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        54,782,464 cusparse64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:45 PM           246,784 fatbinary.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         1,274,880 gpu-library-advisor.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM           205,824 nppc64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         9,744,384 nppial64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         3,953,664 nppicc64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         1,035,264 nppicom64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         7,291,392 nppidei64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        55,641,088 nppif64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        26,491,904 nppig64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         4,767,232 nppim64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        14,943,232 nppist64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM           179,200 nppisu64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         2,629,120 nppitc64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         9,024,512 npps64_90.dll
05/16/2018  11:18 PM           241,664 nvblas64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:45 PM           325,632 nvcc.exe
09/02/2017  03:45 PM               328 nvcc.profile
09/02/2017  03:45 PM        16,261,120 nvdisasm.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        15,747,584 nvgraph64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:45 PM         7,202,304 nvlink.exe
09/02/2017  03:45 PM         4,005,376 nvprof.exe
09/02/2017  03:45 PM           181,248 nvprune.exe
09/02/2017  03:46 PM         3,182,592 nvrtc-builtins64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM        17,302,016 nvrtc64_90.dll
09/02/2017  03:46 PM                53 nvvp.bat
05/16/2018  11:16 PM         7,082,496 ptxas.exe
```

Comment: Can you do `echo %PATH%` in your shell and paste the output here? Also paste output of `dir` on the directory it's in? Just want to confirm it's actually on your path as claimed.

Comment: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\extras\CUPTI\libx64;

Comment: Can you put it in your question? And can you paste the `dir` of the directory that the dll is in as well?

Comment: how did you install CUDA? check in bin directory of cuda if u got cudart64_90.dll. if not then i recommend to install CUDA from network installer.

Comment: follow this steps,


 1) full uninstallation of CUDA Toolkit 9.0 installed using exe(network)
2) installation of CUDA Toolkit 9.0 using exe(local)

Installed Anacondas again. Followed instructions https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows


Activated Tensorflow environment and Installed pandas, numpy, matplotlib, Keras, scipy, sklearn etc. Then open jupyter notebook from the anaconda prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the `tensorflow-1.9` [release branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/25c197e02393bd44f50079945409009dd4d434f8/tensorflow/tools/docker/Dockerfile.devel-gpu#L16), it looks like they used **CUDA 9.0** and **CUDNN 7.1.4**

So I think you should download CUDNN 7.1.4. Hopefully, the issue will be fixed.

You can check everything works by running this handy [script](https://gist.github.com/mrry/ee5dbcfdd045fa48a27d56664411d41c) written by one of the authors of the `tensorflow`. It will show you exactly what is not working right.

EDIT:
For CUDA 10.0 it's CUDNN version 7.6.2.24-1 (see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tools/dockerfiles/dockerfiles/devel-gpu.Dockerfile)).